# Python how to find all unpickle-able items inside an object

Tags: python, pickle

I have a program that uses multiprocessing. I'm trying to share information between each process using multiprocessing.Queue(). This queue does not process items that are un-pickable. I've done some duck testing to check if the object is pickable or not and manually gone through the object to find the un-pickable item. Instead of doing this manually, is there a way to find all the un-pickable items and remove them? The reason to find the un-pickable item is so it can be removed the object won't have issues being passed into the queue.

Here's the stripped down version of the code:

```
# Test that object is pickle-able so results can be transferred
# Exception will be raised if not pickle-able
pickle.dumps(shareInfoObject)

mpQueue.put_nowait(shareInfoObject)
```

Comment: Can you please show your code for this: _I've done some duck testing to check if the object is pickable or not and manually gone through the object to find the un-pickable item._ Posting your existing solution helps others to find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "finding all un-pickleable items". Here's a function which checks whether a given object is pickleable or not:

```
import pickle
def pickleable(obj):
    try:
        pickle.dumps(obj)
    except pickle.PicklingError:
        return False
    return True

# Test
import os
print(pickleable(42))  # True
print(pickleable(os))  # False
```

In Python 2 it's possible to get a different error than `pickle.PicklingError`, and so a more robust (though less careful) option would be to just use `except:` to catch any exception.